# I need that my for loop sums the all the values

Tags: java, loops

I know this might be a repetitive question, but I really need help.
So I need that the number entered, from the for loop gets it sums.
For example, if I enter 5, the for loop should do : 1+2+3+4+5 and show me the result.

Here are the codes.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner x =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int res = x.nextInt();
    int end = res;

        while(res<=0){
            System.out.println("Not good enter again");
            res = x.nextInt();
        }

        for( int ans=0; ans<end; ans++){
            int sum = ans;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `sum` outside of the for loop. It's being recreated on each iteration of the for loop.

Comment: General advice. 1) Write the algorithm out on paper. 2) Add print statements to see what your code does. 3) Use a debugger. 4) [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You don't need a loop to calculate a triangle number.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this:

```
int sum=0;//<-Declare your sum here and initialize to zero
for( int ans=1; ans<=end; ans++){
     sum = sum+ans;    //add every element here with the previous sum
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

You will have to declare sum outside the loop, as if you declare inside the loop it will lose it's previous value with every iteration.

```
Scanner x =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
int res = x.nextInt();
int end = res;

while(res<=0){
    System.out.println("Not good enter again");
    res = x.nextInt();
}
int sum = 0;
for( int ans=0; ans<end; ans++){
    sum = sum + ans;
}

System.out.println(sum);
}
```

And also you should print the sum outside the for loop.